# Change Http to Https for c# web application

Tags: ssl

I have a quick question on opting the SSL Certificate for the Web Application. In the Web Application, am using Kestrel as WebServer and application is not configured in IIS.

For Customers, I install the Application as a Service in Server Machine and its used by the employees only in intranet. Now the address of my application is **http://machineName:port** but I would like to have **https://machineName:port**.

Question 1) Is this possible for the Intranet sites?
Question 2) Will SSL be really needed in this case?
Qeustion 3) SSL works, only if I configure Web Application with IIS?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes it is possible. As long as the certificate is trusted by the clients. You can [create a self signed certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps) and have client machines add it to trusted root certificate authorities in windows. Or if the intranet is using a windows domain, you can have a Certificate Authority trusted by domain computers issue the certificate.
2. SSL is always better even in intranet and localhost scenarios. It ensures site identity, encrypts traffic, etc. Whether it is needed depends on the site. Some browser functionality such as using the camera/mic won't work unless the website is using SSL.
3. Kestrel allows using SSL. Checkout [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-3.1#endpoint-configuration).

Comment: Hi @Sherif Elmetainy, thanks for your reply. Your answer gives me good clarity, but then am very new to this SSL certificate area. So need little more clarity, Should I need to buy a SSL certificate from 3rd party for Certificate Authority or self signed certificate is enough for Production? Another is, On Customer side, in One server machine our application runs as a Window Service, Employees will have access to the application in the Browser using http://serverMachineName:port.This is my scenario.

Comment: If you have control on the Employees PCs, you can use a self-signed certificate or issue a certificate from a Certificate Authority in the domain. By having control, I mean you can add the certificate in their trusted root authority store on each PC. You can also get a free SSL certificate from https://letsencrypt.org/. It will be trusted by all PCs and you won't need to install the certificate on client machine. But `ServerMachineName` won't work when you buy a certificate or get a free one from letsencrypt. The domain must be something.yourcompany.com, etc.